# Android xml increasing variable

Tags: java, android, xml, string

Say I have these lines in strings.xml:

```
<string name="video">Video</string>
<string name="photo">Photo</string>
<string name="text">Text</string>
```

And these lines in my menu.xml file:

```
<item
android:id="@+id/video"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_game_50"
android:title="@string/video"
/>
<item
android:id="@+id/photo"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_help_50"
android:title="@string/photo"
/>
<item
android:id="@+id/text"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_help_50"
android:title="@string/text"
/>
```

I'd like to change this, so that instead of a constant strings of "Video", "Photo", "Text", it would be "Video[i]", etc.. when i is the step number and increases itself according to the times I'm running some intent.

Is it possible?

Comment: Is it natural that you asked questions and don't like to accept any more?

Answer (score 0):

**Unfortunately it is not possible to do that in XML I think.**

You can parametrize your string like this:

```
<string name="string_title">String %1$d</string>
```

Then you have to call

```
int i = 1;
String string = getResources().getString(R.string.string_title, i);
```

Your string will contain "String 1", then you need to assign the string to your view or menu item, like Chintan Rathod suggested.

Comment: You can't, but this is a nice improvement to Chintan's answer.

Comment: @thelawnmowerman yes.. you are right. I didn't involve this part in my answer.

Comment: Thanks guys, but I'm not sure I understood what exactly can be done to solve the problem. Can you please note what code to implement in which file?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.

Try following code. This will set "Title" of your menu item.

```
MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.video);
item.setTitle("Video ["+i+"]");
```

You can set title as you like with other approach provided in another answer like getting string resources or hard coded.

**Edit**

To use **menu** object out of **onCreateOptionsMenu**, use following code.

First declare a global object

```
private Menu menu;
```

Now, assign menu object

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(int selection, Menu menu) {

    this.menu = menu;

    //rest of the code
}
```

Comment: So finally this suppose to be the code:
    int i = 1;
    String string = getResources().getString(R.string.video, i);
    private Menu menu;
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(int selection, Menu menu) {
        this.menu = menu;
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.video);
        item.setTitle("Video ["+i+"]");
    }
?

Comment: @user2517096 thats great.. hope you will upvote or accept the answer if it helped.. :)

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately it cruches. I don't know exactly why. Do you have an idea?

Comment: @user2517096 will help you if you can show your error code

Comment: 11-10 14:16:29.773: W/dalvikvm(2285): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415b8bd8)
11-10 14:16:29.781: E/AndroidRuntime(2285): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-10 14:16:29.781: E/AndroidRuntime(2285): Process: com.google.android.glass.sample.charades, PID: 2285